# Calling Methods on Python's Dictionary Literals

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I'm trying to concatenate some dictionaries.  The best way I've come up with to do that is to use `dict1.update(dict2)`.

This is the code I'm trying to run, but it evaluates to None.  Why?

```
{k:30 for k in [4, 9, 11, 6]}.update({k:31 for k in [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12]})
```

Comment: Because `update` changes the dictionary in-place, and doesn't return anything explicitly

Comment: You're updating the first temporary dictionary with the contents of the second one _in place_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `update` doesn't return a reference to the updated dictionary, you can use the following instead:

```
import itertools
d = dict(itertools.chain({k:30 for k in [...]}.items(),
                         {k:31 for k in [...]}.items()))
```

Answer (score 4):

The `dict.update` method works in-place and therefore always returns `None`.  It is no different than other in-place methods such as `dict.clear` and `list.append`.

Note too that this behavior is mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update):

> `update([other])`
>
> Update the dictionary with the key/value pairs from `other`, overwriting existing keys. **Return `None`**.

Emphasis mine.